# I can't highlight the inner faces after using the "Solidify" modifier. What to do? Blender

Tags: 3d, blender

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhnKT.png

I can't highlight the inner faces after using the "Solidify" modifier. What to do? Blender

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the modifier first.
All geometry within your modifier stack is procedural, and cannot be edited before applying. You first have to enter **ObjectMode** and then, in the modifiers tab, click the arrow icon on the top right corner of your **Solidify** modifier and select **Apply** from the drop-down menu.
After this you should be able to select the newly created faces in **EditMode**

[image]